What does "syntax tax" mean in respect to the TC39 pipe-operator proposal?
Reading the ECMAScript TC39 pipe-operator proposal; it mentions "syntax tax" when comparing 2 possible alternatives for the pipe-operator implementation
(see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator?tab=readme-ov-file#hack-pipes-favor-more-common-expressions).
I interpret this to mean that for example extra syntax is required. E.g. for F#-pipes you need to wrap non-unary functions in a lambda taking a single argument to work. So the "tax" is the added extra syntax that is needed to make that work.
(Perhaps this is more a question of general use of English, and I'm not used to how "tax" is used in other contexts.)

Yes, that's exactly what it means. It's just a metaphor. The "tax" is having to type extra characters in some cases.

Citizens of the anglo-sphere have never liked taxes so the connotation is almost always negative ;p. Seriously though, your interpretation is perfect.
